# How to run EdgeOS configuration commands in python fabric

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, python

I'm trying to programmatically update configuration in EdgeOS using a python script. I'm using fabric as an ssh client. https://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/index.html

Below "---original question---" describes the problem, but I think I've hit on the source of the issue, but not the solution. Fabric ssh's into the router in non-interactive mode, and as such doesn't get the full bash configuration. The `configure` command isn't available, nor `show` nor other router management commands. The .bashrc file in the router is this:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# enable completion
source /etc/bash_completion.d/vyatta-cfg
source /etc/bash_completion.d/vyatta-op

unset HISTFILE
```

So I can see I'm not sourcing the bash_completion files. I tried doing that manually in python: `c.run("source /etc/bash_completion.d/vyatta-cfg")`, but it doesn't seem to work. My next best solution is to find the hard path to those commands, but I'm not sure where to look.

---original question---

what I'd like to do is to create small configuration changes such as:

```
configure
set interfaces ethernet eth2 vif 20 disable
commit
save
```

However, the `configure` command fails when I run it through fabric. I notice, when I'm in an ssh session, the `configure` command creates a new sub-session or something. I'm not sure of the term.

```
$ configure
[edit]
#
```

script so far:

```
from fabric import Connection
c = Connection('routerip')
c.run("configure")
```

And the error:

```
vbash: configure: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decorator.py", line 231, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 23, in opens
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 763, in run
    return self._run(self._remote_runner(), command, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/invoke/context.py", line 113, in _run
    return runner.run(command, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fabric/runners.py", line 83, in run
    return super().run(command, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/invoke/runners.py", line 395, in run
    return self._run_body(command, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/invoke/runners.py", line 451, in _run_body
    return self.make_promise() if self._asynchronous else self._finish()
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/invoke/runners.py", line 518, in _finish
    raise UnexpectedExit(result)
invoke.exceptions.UnexpectedExit: Encountered a bad command exit code!

Command: 'configure'

Exit code: 127

Stdout: already printed

Stderr: already printed
```

Comment: Just for your understanding, `source` in Bash is as if you typed the content of the sourced file into the shell. If you run `c.run("source some_file")`, it may be executed in a a shell, and the shell may be terminated afterwards. If this sets environment variables or other volatile configuration settings within the shell, that is lost when the shell is closed. Try `c.run("FOO=BAR")` and `c.run("echo $FOO")` to find out whether it's the same shell or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use the absolute path for configure (if it's a command)

```
/path/to/configure
set interfaces ethernet eth2 vif 20 disable
commit
save
```

which you can obtain from your interactive session

```
type configure
```

If it enters an interactive session you should need to provide the input in some way though.

Comment: `type` gets me more information, the commands are aliases to `_vyatta_op_run`, and I can source the vyatta files, and use that aliased command. However, it still doesn't help with the "inner session" problem. As soon as I run `_vyatta_op_run configure`, I'm jumped into a "configure" session, and fabric errors out

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change configuration from python that I've found is the create a bash script, copy that to the router, and run it from fabric.

turn-off-wifi.bash

```
#!/bin/vbash
source /opt/vyatta/etc/functions/script-template
configure
set interfaces ethernet $1 disable
commit
exit
```

toggle.py

```
c = Connection(host="ubnt@192.168.1.1")
t = transfer.Transfer(c)
t.put("turn-off-wifi.bash")
c.run("chmod +x ./turn-off-wifi.bash && ./turn-off-wifi.bash %s" % (interfaceName))
```

(I'm parameterizing the ethernet interface name)